# How should I approach a company about furthering a science idea I have partially developed?

Tags: contracts, company, business, research

I'm a scientist, 52 years old.
For 5 years, I have developed a personal research project, in a private room which belongs to my associate. It is about the interaction between living cells and Electro-magnetic fields, with wide applications to medicine. I worked alone, learning specialized domains of electronics and building a machine supposed to produce a biological effect. I also invested much money, about 200,000$, which is a lot in my country. The idea is based on previous research by a radio-electronic engineer of genius in the eighteenth. I have now finished the machine and I can show it. Unfortunately, I am blocked because in order to show some effect, I need to perform experiments on living animals (say mice) which involves many procedures and costs a lot of money. Furthermore I probably need more powerful emitters for the machine, which I cannot afford.

I thought to interest investors but the project is still in a "research" state; I am not a professor (I have only an MA), so, I don't think they will trust me and invest money in my research project.

I discovered there is a company in my country which has developed a product based on similar principles, but is still very different. There is only one company like that in my country, and probably very few worldwide. This company was funded by a professor in biology in 2005, and has successfully developed its product and penetrated European markets. They are now employing about 1000 persons worldwide, most of them in my country. Perhaps I could approach them?

- I am not officially a company, everything here is private;
- Their company is located at about 3 hours from my town;
- I am certain I know things they don't know about the principles they are trying to exploit; I did a very thorough work of research about the work of the aforementioned genius, and I have even documents which are difficult to obtain. Furthermore, as explained above, I have something that could be called a "prototype";
- During these years, I have developed good skills to build complicated electronics devices. Moreover, I have developed abilities to build complex electromagnetic prototypes at comparatively very low price.
- I think that with some relatively moderated investment (500,000 - 1,000,000 $), I can improve my prototype and show its effects, perhaps even obtain a prototype for a definite medical product.

I would like to propose them something, ideally to be a subsidiary company in my town, or at least to be employed by them to develop a branch of their company in my town, under conditions that would guarantee some independence. But I don't know what exactly to propose them, and most importantly, how to approach them and make them a proposition. Could you give me advice?

Comment: That's more an entrepreneurship question than a workplace question as we usually define it. I think you need a lawyer's advice on how to talk to them without jeopardizing your own intellectual property. Though the fact that you haven't proven it works makes its value questionable.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to propose them something, ideally to be a subsidiary
> company in my town, or at least to be employed by them to develop a
> branch of their company in my town, under conditions that would
> guarantee some independence. But I don't know what exactly to propose
> them, and most importantly, how to approach them and make them a
> proposition. Could you give me advice?

You should talk to a good lawyer with business startup and IP experience, or whatever is the equivalent in your country.

At it's base, this is a legal queston, and isn't really a question for non-professionals.